# Oracle index behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

When I query my table for a specific object like this, I'll get an empty result set:

```
SELECT 
   a, b, c, valid_to, pk_mykey, myobject
FROM
   myschema.mytable
WHERE
   valid_to = to_date('31.12.9999 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND
   pk_mykey > 0
AND
   myobject = 'ABC.123';
```

But I know the record has to be in the table!

So I use this query and it will suddenly show up:

```
SELECT 
   /*+ NO_INDEX(mytable myindex) */
   a, b, c, valid_to, pk_mykey, myobject
FROM
   myschema.mytable
WHERE
   valid_to = to_date('31.12.9999 23:59:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND
   pk_mykey > 0
AND
   myobject = 'ABC.123';
```

So by using the index the records won't show, but without index it will? How is this possible? What am I missing here? What is wrong with my table and/or my index? Any idea how I can solve this?

(DBMS is Oracle 11g EE 11.2.0.2.0 64bit)

Comment: what is the diff b/w the 2 queries?

Comment: @ling.s: the `NO_INDEX` hint

Comment: @ling.s: yes, exactly what a_horse_with_no_name said, the hint. query1 gives me no record at all. query2 exactly 1 record (as it is supposed to be) where myobject = 'ABC.123' and the other conditions apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you confirmed that there is a difference in the execution plan?

If you are getting different results with and without the index then I'd consider dropping the index and recreating it. Do not just rebuild the index, as the new segment will be based on the data in the old, and if you do have a corruption problem that will not fix it.

Comment: yes, query1 uses the index (unique scan). query2 does a full table scan, no index included.

Comment: Is that an index on myobject and valid_to?

Comment: exactly, a unique index on myobject and valid_to. also there is a tablespace for all indexes (myschema_idx) and a tablespace for all tables (myschema_tbl).

Comment: I don't think the tablespaces are relevant, but try the index replacement if you can.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically the content of your index can be "invalid" due to some Oracle bug. This could happen on some early RAC releases.
Try to execute the statement

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable VALIDATE STRUCTURE CASCADE;
```

This will "crosscheck" table content against it's indexes. Or try to rebuild the index.

Comment: don't you mean ANALYZE TABLE? If so, I'm not the DBA and hence have not the privileges to run such a query...

Comment: It's "alter table" its non destructive statement and can be "safely" executed even on prod systems. It just generates a lot of IO. If the crosscheck fails a dump file will be created in the udump_dest. This command does not require DBA privs, you can execute it as schema owner too.

Comment: `ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option`